# ios using blocks for assets library

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, alassetslibrary

I need to use the assets library: i've found a snippets like this:

```
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                        usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                        failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Failure");
                        }];
```

and the compiler gives me the error like doesn't recognize the block ^.

is there a setting or something to enable the blocks in the project?
thanks in advance

here is the complete error / code:
https://skitch.com/ghiboz/grpyc/xcode

Paolo

Comment: what does your assetGroupEnumerator declaration look like in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer -- Looks like you need to add the AssetsLibrary framework to your project.

My new answer -- for your asset enumerations, get rid of the "struct" keyword in your block declarations. You don't need them.

e.g.

```
void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
```

and

```
void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset * result, NSUInteger index, BOOL * stop)
```

Comment: did you add `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` to the top of the file where you're using the block?

Comment: Check out my answer above.  You need to get rid of the keyword "struct" in your blocks declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using GCC instead of Clang? It has problems recognizing the signatures of blocks in many cases.

Comment: I mean GCC has problems, you should be using Clang. In your target settings you'll see "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" Change that to Clang if it isn't already set as such.

Comment: https://skitch.com/ghiboz/gryyr/xcode I have this and in my options there is only APPLE LLVM AND LLVM GCC 4.2

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere then. show what assetGroupEnumerator is

Comment: look the first post, i've uploaded a shot with the code: that is like this: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/